# Rubygems issue when runnuing rails new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Sorry this might be a basic question but I am new to rails.
I wanted to start a new rails project by the command `rails new projName`. In the middle of the process I got this message:

```
run  bundle install

Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

bundle install --path vendor/bundle

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

Password:
```

I wasn't so sure whether I should give my password but I searched and [I found that it is safe to do that](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/1028) (or at least that what I understood).

At the end I got this warning:

```
Warning: You're using Rubygems 2.0.14 with Spring. Upgrade to at least Rubygems 2.1.0 and run `gem pristine --all` for better startup performance.
* bin/rake: spring inserted
* bin/rails: spring inserted
```

so I tried to run `gem install Rubygems` and I got:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'Rubygems' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: ruby_gem, ruby_gem_eg, ruby-rets, ruby-gen, rubyless
```

I tried `gem install rubygems-update` and I got:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

I have already installed rails through RVM, and I am not sure why I am having those permission issues. As I am not experienced with gems I am stuck and don't know how to fix these issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here is how I solved it for reference. I saw the a similar issue in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2319212/rails-requires-rubygems-1-3-2-please-install-rubygems-and-try-again-i-have)

A step by step solution would be:

1. Run `gem env`. You should see a list of paths like so under GEM PATHS:

   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0

   /Users/sam/.gem/ruby/2.0.0

   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
2. Open your ~/.bashrc file and add the paths as follows:

   export GEM_HOME=/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0

   export PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME:/Users/sam/.gem/ruby/2.0.0:/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
3. Open a new shell and run the `gem install rubygems-update`. Everything should run fine now without sudo.

Answer (score 9):

It should be sufficient to run a:

```
gem update --system
```

to upgrade Rubygem to the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

Try `sudo gem install rubygems-update`

Comment: I thought it is not recommended to use sudo when working with gems, why would that be an exception?

Comment: Yep, it's not recommended to install gems with sudo. Might cause problems afterwards.